# Using a foreach loop to retrieve TextBox's within a GroupBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have ten group boxes in a `WinForm`. Each group box contains 10 text boxes, and I have defined each `TextBox` name.  How can I get each text box using a foreach loop?

Comment: Please tag the question correctly.

Comment: -1 for: tag, format. lower case.. etc.

Comment: First find the controls of type groupbox then plunge in and get the controls of the type textbox within it

Comment: If you need to do this you are doing somthing wrong. You have the names of the boxes already right?

Answer (score 16):

```
 foreach(Control gb in this.Controls)
 {
       if(gb is GroupBox)
       {
          foreach(Control tb in gb.Controls)
          {
             if(tb is TextBox)
             {
                 //here is where you access all the textboxs.
             }
          }
       }
 }
```

But if you **have defined each TextBox name**
What's the point to get each `TextBox` by a loop?

You could define a `List<TextBox>` to hold reference of each `TextBox` while creating them, then just go though the `List` to get access of each `TextBox`.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my suggestion:

```
foreach(var groupBox in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
{
    foreach(var textBox in groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

Or having it in one loop:

```
foreach (var textBox in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().SelectMany(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try following code,

```
Control.ControlCollection coll = this.Controls;
foreach(Control c in coll) {
  if(c != null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var ctrl in gbDatabaseColumns.Controls)
{
     if (ctrl is DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit)
     {
        StoreTextEdit(config, (ctrl as DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit));
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (Control txx in groupBox2.Controls)
{
    if (txx is TextBox)
        txx.Text = "";
    if (txx is ComboBox)
        txx.Text = "";
    // if (txx is DateTimePicker)
    //     txx.Text = ""; Datetimepicker text can't be erased
}
```

Comment: i could not able to edit the post. Please format the answer by write code in between ``` code ```. And add some description also

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).