# using Foreach loop to retrieve textboxes text in groupbox within tabpages

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a foreach loop to retrieve TextBox's within a GroupBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224261/using-a-foreach-loop-to-retrieve-textboxs-within-a-groupbox)

I have a tab control and these control have 10 tab page,each page have 10 groupboxes and each groupbox have 10 textboxes,how can i get all textboxes text using foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
  foreach (TabPage t in tabControl1.TabPages)
    {
        foreach (Control c in t.Controls)
        {
            if (c is GroupBox)
            {
                foreach (Control cc in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (cc is TextBox)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(cc.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

Helper func:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> PrefixTreeToList<T>(this T root, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildrenFunc) {
    if (root == null) yeild break;
    if (getChildrenFunc == null) {
         throw new ArgumentNullException("getChildrenFunc");
    }
    yield return root;
    IEnumerable children = getChildrenFunc(root);
    if (children == null) yeild break;
    foreach (var item in children) {
         foreach (var subitem in PrefixTreeToList(item, getChildrenFunc)) {
              yield return subitem;
         }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.PrefixTreeToList(x => x.Controls).OfType<TextBox>()) {
    //Do something with tb.Text;
}
```

I think, I need explain a little what I'm doing here, this code walks through full tree of controls and selects those of them, which have type TextBox, please let me know if something is unclear.