# Copy content of textboxes to others

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, copy-paste, groupbox

I have two `GroupBox`es and a `Button`, in each `GroupBox` I've 40 `TextBox`es.

How can I copy the contents of the first 40 `TextBox`es to the second ones programmatically ?

Comment: What is the rule to map a textbox in one group to the other one?

Comment: You are much more likely to get a good answer if you show what you have tried.

Comment: Iterate through them like [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224261/using-a-foreach-loop-to-retrieve-textboxs-within-a-groupbox)

Comment: did you try what I said ?

Answer (score 2):

Well , you need to use a pattern for `name` of `textBox`es so we can loop throw them !

for example I added two `groupBox`es to my project called `groupBox1` and `groupBox2`
in `groupBox1` i have some `textbox`es with name of

```
textbox1_gb1
textbox2_gb1
textbox3_gb1
.
.
.
textbox40_gb1
```

also in `groupBox2` I have used the same pattern , just changed the `gb1` to `gb2` :

```
textbox1_gb2
textbox2_gb2
textbox3_gb2
.
.
.
textbox40_gb2
```

and now here's the solution :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
{
    ((TextBox)(groupBox2.Controls["textBox" + i + "_gb2"])).Text = ((TextBox)(groupBox1.Controls["textBox" + i + "_gb1"])).Text;
}
```

the most important thing here is the name pattern ! hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

create testbox name like for example

```
testbox1
testbox2
testbox3
.
.
.
testbox40
```

Now use this code:

```
    for (int Cont = 1; Cont <= 40; Cont++)
    {   
        TextBox testboxvalue = (TextBox)groupboxname.Controls.Find("testbox" + Cont, false).FirstOrDefault();
        //Do what you want here, example: 
        String variable = testboxvalue.Name;
    }
```